# Multiple integral over two dependent beta distributions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, beta-function

I want to evaluate this multiple integral:
$$ \iiint\limits_{ \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i=1,\ \ \ x_1,\, x_2,\,x_3,\, x_4\, \ge \,0  } (x_1+x_2)^{N1} (x_3+x_4)^{N2} (x_1+x_3)^{N3} (x_2+x_4)^{N4} \, dX$$

For context, this problem comes up when computing the marginal likelihood of data consisting of two dependent binary variables $(a,b)$. The conditional probability distribution for $B$ given $A$ is:
\begin{align}
P(B=0\mid A=0)=x_1+x_2; & &  P(B=1\mid A=0)=x_3+x_4 \\
P(B=0\mid A=1)=x_1+x_3; & &  P(B=0\mid A=1)=x_2+x_4  
\end{align}

The marginal likelihood turns into this integral, where $N_i$ are the counts of $B\mid A$ in the data.

This looks like a dirichlet integral of type 1, but the problem is that I am unable to separate out the integral into integrals over fewer variables.

I have tried:

1. Use dirac delta function to remove the simplex and then use laplace
   transform to find a [closed form solution](http://dnquark.com/blog/2012/05/integrating-dirichlet-distributions/). However, it does not 
   work here because the integrals are not separable.
2. Using the variable substitution for beta variables as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186063/find-symbolic-integral-for-expression-containing-multivariate-polynomials).
3. Interpret the equation as product of two Beta functions: $B(N_1 +1, N_2 +1), B(N_3 +1, N_4 +1)$.
   However, I am stuck because $x_i$ are shared across the terms.

Any ideas?

Comment: By using the substitutions $x_i=y_i^2,\; dx_i = 2y_i\,dy_i$ the integration domain becomes part of a sphere and you may switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: thanks @JackD'Aurizio This works, however I get stuck again in separating the terms after substituting $y_1^2+y_2^2=r_{12}^2; y_3^2 + y_4^2=r_{34}^2$. The first two terms factor out, but then I have $(r_{12}^2 cos^2\theta_{12} +r_{34}^2 sin^2\theta_{34})^{N3} (r_{34}^2 cos^2\theta_{34} +r_{12}^2 sin^2\theta_{12})^{N4}$. How should I evaluate this? appreciate your help!

Comment: These look more like marginal probabilities than conditional probabilities.  I suspect something is wrong with the problem from the beginning. $\qquad$

Comment: Could you write $r_{12}^2\cos^2\theta_{12}$ instead of $r_{12}^2cos^2\theta_{12}$?  That is standard usage.  When you write $a\cos b$, coded as a\cos b, then you automatically get proper spacing to the left and right of $\cos$, and $\cos$ is not italicized, and the spacing depends on the context, as seen when you type $a\cos(b). \qquad$

Comment: @Amit: you are taking polar coordinates as defined for the $3$-dimensional sphere, but I was actually suggesting to use polar coordinates as defined for a $4$-dimensional sphere, depending on $3$ angles.

Comment: That should bring your integral into a generalization of Euler's beta function provided by a hypergeometric $\phantom{}_2 F_1$ function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy sorry about the incorrect formatting. Unfortunately I am unable to edit my comment now.

I am not sure about your comment on marginal versus conditional probabilities. My problem is about finding the marginal likelihood of the data, where  $P(B|A)$ is as described above. This integration term is a part of the formula that I am unable to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JackD'Aurizio I am trying the 4 dimensional co-ordinates now: $r, \phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3$, but am unable to reach a closed form (assuming you meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type) function as a generalization of Euler's beta function).
Would be great if you could provide some more hints.

Answer (score 1):

First observe this simplification:
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1} \int_0^{1-x_1-x_2} (x_1+x_2)^{N_1}(1-x_1-x_2)^{N_2} (x_1+x_3)^{N_3} (1-x_1-x_3)^{N_4} \,dx_3 \,dx_2 \,dx_1 \\[12pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x_1}\left( (x_1+x_2)^{N_1}(1-x_1-x_2)^{N_2} \int_0^{1-x_1-x_2} (x_1+x_3)^{N_3} (1-x_1-x_3)^{N_4} \,dx_3\right) \,dx_2 \,dx_1
\end{align}
In the innermost integral, $x_1$ and $x_2$ remain constant as $x_3$ goes from $0$ to $1-x_1-x_2$; hence the step above can be done.

Now look at the inner integral:
$$
\int_0^{1-x_1-x_2} (x_1+x_3)^{N_3} (1-x_1-x_3)^{N_4} \,dx_3 = \int_{x_1}^{1-x_2} u^{N_3} (1-u)^{N_4} \, du.
$$
This is a doubly incomplete Beta function.  By expanding via the binomial theorem and integrating term by term, you can write it as a sum, but I'm not optimistic about a closed form.

This last integral is of course a polynomial function of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: thanks @michael-hardy do you know of a reliable technique to approximate this integral if a closed form cannot be achieved? I'm happy using a numerical solution too.